# Why are keys in the quasidistribution larger than the maximum number allowed by the number of qubits?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I use the IBM' Qiskit Runtime Sampler on a 4 qubits circuit.

```
with Session(backend=backend):
            sampler = Sampler()
            result = sampler.run(qc, shots=nshots).result()
            qd = result.quasi_dists[0]
            print("qd",qd)
```

I get the following quasi-distribution:

qd {44: 0.0830078125, 36: 0.060546875, 4: 0.0595703125, 56: 0.0673828125, 40: 0.0634765625, 52: 0.0576171875, 8: 0.0625, 0: 0.0673828125, 48: 0.0615234375, 60: 0.0634765625, 12: 0.07421875, 16: 0.0556640625, 28: 0.0634765625, 20: 0.0478515625, 32: 0.0546875, 24: 0.0576171875}

How it is possible for some key values need more than 4 qubits?
(same behavior with different backends)

Comment: The reason is this: I used `measure_all()`, but I accidentally set the number of classical bits to be fewer than the number of qubits. That's why this happened. However, it would be better if the system could clearly indicate this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is indeed that you used `measure_all`, but not for the reason you described.

What `measure_all` actually does is first adding a **new** classical register whose size is equal to the number of qubits in the circuit, and will then measure all the qubits in this new register.

Hence, if you added a `ClassicalRegister` by yourself, your circuit will actually have two classical registers.

This can be seen from the keys you got in your quasidistribution: all the keys have their two least significant bits set to $0$. I'm thus guessing that you created your circuit using `QuantumCircuit(4, 2)`. Since no qubit is measured in the first classical register, it stays in the $00$ "state".

Take the following code as an example:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(4, 2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.cx(0, 2)
qc.cx(0, 3)
qc.measure_all()
qc.draw("mpl")

backend = service.get_backend("ibmq_qasm_simulator")
with Session(backend=backend):
            sampler = Sampler()
            result = sampler.run(qc, shots=1024).result()
            qd = result.quasi_dists[0]
            print("qd",qd)
```

This prints `qd {60: 0.48828125, 0: 0.51171875}`. Note that `60` in binary is written `111100`. As expected, the last two bits are set to `0`, and the first 4 are all set to `1`.

Note that in this example, the `Sampler` that is used is that of Qiskit Runtime. Now, take the following code:

```
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler

sampler = Sampler()
result = sampler.run(qc, shots=1024).result()
qd = result.quasi_dists[0]
print("qd",qd)
```

This fails with `QiskitError: 'Some classical bits are not used for measurements. the number of classical bits (6), the used classical bits ({2, 3, 4, 5}).'`.

Thus, there's a discrepancy between these two `Sampler`s. I personally would have expected the to behave in the same way, but it appears it's not the case. I would encourage you to ask on the [Qiskit Github](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues) whether this is an expected distinction between the twos. Either you will have helped to report a bug, or you will have an explanation as to why these functions behave differently.